# Cant perform a clean drag and drop in HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I wonder if anybody could offer some advice on this drag and drop issue. I have 4 balls that appear randomly in a web app when it is started. Each has a random number with only one containing the correct answer. This correct ball is identified when it is dropped into a dropzone. The problem I am having is that when a ball is dragged I am trying to remove it completely from the source area (which is a table) while it is dragged to the dropzone. The ball should then reappear in the source area after a set time of 6 milliseconds.

HTML code:
the source table:

```
<td><div id="bball1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" ondrag="drag(event)"></div></td>
<td><div id="bball2" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" ondrag="drag(event)"></div></td>
<td><div  id="bball3" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" ondrag="drag(event)" ></div></td>
<td><div id="bball4"  draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" ondrag="drag(event)" ></div></td>
```

the dropzone:

```
<div id="drop_zone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="dragStart(event)"></div>
```

the Javascript:

```
function dragStart(ev) {                                           
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));

var node = document.getElementById(ev.target.getAttribute('id'));    
if (node.parentNode) {
  var parent = node.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(node);
  setTimeout(function() {parent.appendChild(node); }, 600);
  }

 return true;
}

function dragOver(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();  
ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';     
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
// math code that is triggered by the event here.
}
```

What is happening is that when I drag the ball at the source it is removed and returns after the set timeout perfectly. The problem is that it is completely remove all together. It does not drag to the dropzone. When I remove the line

```
parent.removeChild(node);
```

then the dragging process works perfectly but the ball is not removed from the source table.

If anyone could offer any help on this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

dragging and dropping in a table can be tricky,

you don't want to move the cell,

but the content of the cell.

It can appear smoother to append the dragged item to a transparent container

for the move and append it to its new parent when the move is complete,

than to remove a node and 'reappear' it.

Comment: Do you mean that I should change the source of the dragged items from a table to maybe a list or simply change the background on the body's container to transparent or both?